# Wordpress profile permissions to select contact reference field

Tags: wordpress, profile, permissions, contact-reference

We are in WordPress, which is new to me. We have a registration profile that includes a custom field which is a contact reference field filtered to include only a specific group of contacts. When I'm logged in, this shows up and works great on the profile, but an anonymous user can't even see the custom field on the registration profile. The custom data set is set to public, don't know if that matters.

What permissions do I need to give an anonymous user so that they can make a selection from the filtered contact reference field?

I've installed the User Role Editor plugin to hopefully give me the flexibility to do this- also please let me know if a different plugin is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission you're looking for is `CiviCRM: access contact reference fields`. You can view the list of permissions from civicrm menu too via `Administer => Users and permissions => Permissions`

[image]

and then click on `WordPress Access Control` link displayed on the page.

[image]

Comment: That worked! I didn't know there was a WordPress Access control; I was trying to use the User Role Editor plugin, and it has some CiviCRM permissions, but not the Contact Reference one. Thanks.